# Context for "there is a Jew behind me, come and kill him"

Tags: hadith-interpretation, jews, violence

What context, if any, is there for the following, which is referred to in the charter of at least one major political organisation nowadays?

> The Day of Judgement will not come about until Muslims fight the Jews,
>   when the Jew will hide behind stones and trees. The stones and trees
>   will say O Muslims, O Abdullah, there is a Jew behind me, come and
>   kill him. Only the Gharkad tree, (the Boxthorn tree) would not do that
>   because it is one of the trees of the Jews. (related by al-Bukhari and
>   Muslim)

Comment: Just did a Google search- it's on the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_and_antisemitism#Hadith
As shown by the references it's part of the Sahih Muslim.

Answer (score 6):

The hadith has many versions from different narrators:

> Abdullah b. 'Umar reported that Allaah's Messenger (sallAllaahu alayhi
>   wa sallam) said: The Jews will fight against you and you will gain
>   victory over them until the stone would say: Muslim, here is a Jew
>   behind me; kill him.
>
> Ibn 'Umar reported Allaah's Messenger (sallAllaahu alayhi wa sallam)
>   as saying: You will fight against the Jews and you will kill them
>   until even a stone would say: Come here, Muslim, there is a Jew
>   (hiding himself behind me) ; kill him.
>
> Abdullah b. 'Umar reported Allaah's Messenger (sallAllaahu alayhi wa
>   sallam) as saying: You and the Jews would fight against one another
>   until a stone would say: Muslim, here is a Jew behind me; come and
>   kill him.
>
> Abu Huraira reported Allaah's Messenger (sallAllaahu alayhi wa
>   sallam) as saying: The last hour would not come unless the Muslims
>   will fight against the Jews and the Muslims would kill them until the
>   Jews would hide themselves behind a stone or a tree and a stone or a
>   tree would say: Muslim, or the servant of Allaah, there is a Jew
>   behind me; come and kill him; but the tree Gharqad would not say, for
>   it is the tree of the Jews.
>
> Ref: [Sahih Muslim](http://www.sahihmuslim.com/sps/smm/sahihmuslim.cfm?scn=dspchaptersfull&BookID=41&ChapterID=1211)

It describes a war/combat between faithful Muslims and Jews after the time of prophet and before the last hour. Why the war will happen is not mentioned. Who will initiate the war is also unclear but the first hadith seems to indicate that Jews will initiate it.

Since there was no event [after the prophet till present] that resembles the hadith, it is generally considered that the event hasn't happened and it will happen in future. When it will happen is unknown but it is part of sunni belief that it will happen.

Shia Muslims reject the narrations of both of the narrators from whom this hadith is transmitted, thereby they reject all of the hadiths cited above.

This hadith has no effect in Sunni Islamic jurisprudence. It is about a future event not law.

Answer (score 2):

The Hadith depicts a certain time in the future, the context is not mentioned so we don't know much except the fact that this is prophesied to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger صلى الله عليه وسلم  as saying: "The Last Hour will not come until the Muslims fight against the Jews and the Muslims kill them to the extent that the Jews will hide behind a rock or a tree and the rock or the tree will say: O' Muslim, the servant of Allah, there is a Jew behind me; come and kill him; but the Gharqad tree ( Boxthorn tree) will not say that because it is the tree of the Jews." (Sahih Muslim) The Jews are currently planting lots of Gharqad trees in Israel to protect them.

Well, this hadith is about the end of Times and there is no " o Abdullah ".

As muslims, we think that when the Times will come the Antechrist ( we call him al Massih al Dajjal ) will come on and try to convinced people that he is God but of course that he is not but God will give them abilities as killing people and them bring them back to life or ordonning to Djinns to take the appearance of deceaded people to convinced them that he must be worshipped and he will try to get worshippers.

He will come in every city exept Mecqua and Medina and he will see every humain beeing in 40 days. This will be the worst trial for humanity in islam.

He will arrived in a city where muslims will take refuge the city of QOUM ( we don't really know which city it's represent ). He will get around the city with his army of worshippers and he will try to enter to kill them but the city have like a wall all around so they could not enter.

Then on the city of Damascus we think the the Prophet Isa ( Jesus ) pbuh will come back to Earth and he will go to the city of Qoum to help the muslims. He will arrived for the time of the prayer of the morning and the imam will not regonized this man.
This imam is the imam of the end of Time imam al Mahdiand he will be in a community of 1200 muslims ( the number of muslims at time period ) so he will know everybody.
When he will see Isa pbuh he will know who he is and he will know that he is imam al Mahdi. He will let him the place to lead the prayer but Isa pbuh will refused and will pray in the row as every other muslim.

After the prayer he will ask to open the doors to face al Dajjal and his army. When the fake Messiah will see the real Messiah he will run away but Isa pbuh will catch him up and kill him with his swords.

Then he will kill his followers to retablish the real religion of God. As we know, the Jews are waiting for their Messiah to come. So they will all follow al Dajjal.That's why he will kill the Jews and the rocks and trees will talk to inform Isa pbuh of where they are hiding so he could kill them all for disbeliving in God all Powerful.

Abu Huraira narrated that Prophet Mohammad صلى الله عليه وسلم  said: "There is no prophet between me and him (Jesus Christ عليه السلام ). He shall descend so, recognize him when you see him. He is a man of medium height, (his complexion) is between reddish and white; he will be between (or dressed in) two slightly yellowish garments; His head looks as if it is dripping water even though it is not wet. He will fight people in the cause (for the sake) of Islam, will break the Cross and kill the swine (pig) and  abolish Jizya (tax on Christians and Jews); and Allah will put an end to all religious sects  except Islam during his (Jesus') time. He (Jesus) will slay the Antichrist (Dajjal) and he will stay in the World for 40 years. Then, he will die and the Muslims will perform the funeral prayer for him." (Abu Dawud and Musnad Ahmad)

http://www.discoveringislam.org/return_of_jesus.htm

http://www.discoveringislam.org/anti-christ.htm

you can also look for articles about the end of Time in Islam and the major signs.

Comment: If you knew even a little bit of Arabic you would know that "Abdallah" and "servant of Allah" are the same.

Answer (score -1):

The answer from "Allah Knows Best" is sheer Apologia. The Qur'an itself condemns ALL Jews to "Hell"" unless they admit that the Torah is false for Jews having supposedly edited out all Prophecy related to the coming of Muhammad. In short, 100% of Jews are going to "Hell." Ergo, IF all Jews are going to "Hell" then all that "bedrock of humanity" is contrived.

As for "accuracy of Hadith," all Sahih Hadith are considered sacrosanct. Without Hadith there could be no ritual behavior within Islam. It dictates everything from birth, how to treat newborns, to death with funerary customs and mourning. More to the point, there are more than 30 Sahih Hadith all saying the very same thing, from 3 Sahih Compilers so total fail on the Apologetics.

The context was described a Shi'a poster (with the very long post) but Sunna understanding of it is very close to that and identical so far as the blatant Anti Semitism.

Comment: Can you please provide a citation for the claims in the first paragraph?

Answer (score -3):

The accuracy of any Hadith is not absolute, but the correct interpretation of this should be that when one believer (Muslim) so hates another believer (a jew) the end is near.  We, Muslims and Jews, are supposed to be the bedrock of humanity.  We share a common history and a common future, and if we are so lost...so blinded by our hatred, then our loss of faith ( end of times) is complete.

Comment: Sounds like a interesting theory but could you elaborate it or add some references. I strongly suggest you to edit your answer and read [answer].

Comment: Jews aren't believers, one of the requirements of Islam is to believe on Prophet Mohammad (PBUH), they don't, so they are officially Kafir.